# How to reload the quote or cart in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, quote, totals

I am working on ajax cart.
When i update the cart qty, I am trying to reload the quote but its not loading properly

```
$this->cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates()->save();
$this->cart->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
$this->cart->getQuote()->collectTotals();
$this->cart->getQuote()->save();
```

How to reload the quote so that total calculation should happen properly 
in magento1 we use cart::init()

Comment: did you get any success on this?

Comment: did you get any success on this? i am getting same  problem

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may helps you

After add to cart run this code:

```
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PublicCookieMetadata;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;
```

in constructor:

```
    CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
    CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
    SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager,
```

After product was added to cart

```
$metadata = $this->_cookieMetadataFactory
        ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
        ->setPath('/');

$sectiondata = json_decode($this->_cookieManager->getCookie('section_data_ids'));

$sectiondata->cart += 1000;

$this->_cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
    'section_data_ids',
    json_encode($sectiondata),
    $metadata
);
```

Before trying above code try with frontend/section.xml :

```
 <action name="NAMESPACE/MODULE/CARTUPDATE/">
     <section name="cart"/>
 </action>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Your JS

like this

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function($,customerData){
    return function (config){
        var ajaxUrl = config.ajaxUrl;
        $("#addtoCart").on("click",function (event){
            event.preventDefault();
            let param = {
                Sku : $("#productSku").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                showLoader: true,
                url: ajaxUrl,
                data: param,
                type: "POST"
            }).done(function (data) {
                // you can add more section with comma seprated
                let cartSection = ['cart'];
                // if you want to invalidate previous data
                customerData.invalidate(sections);
                //Reload Secion
                customerData.reload(cartSection, true);
            });
        });
    }
});
```